# In ASP Core, where do the parameters of the POST controller method come from when the form doesn't match the prototype?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the ms docs [.NET core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency) the Edit View posts all data for the department but the Post controller method only accepts id and row version. In the delete method only the DepartmentID and RowVersion are posted but the Controller Delete post method accepts a Full Department instance.  Where does this instance come from because it determines how concurrency error will be handled. Is the model for the page secretly passed instead?

### Edit View

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Department

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<h4>Department</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="DepartmentID" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="RowVersion" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Budget" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Budget" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Budget" class="text-danger">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StartDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StartDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="text-danger">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="InstructorID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="InstructorID" class="form-control" asp-
                    items="ViewBag.InstructorID">
                    <option value="">-- Select Administrator --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="InstructorID" class="text-danger">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

### Edit Post in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id, byte[] rowVersion)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var departmentToUpdate = await _context.Departments.Include(i =>         
i.Administrator).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.DepartmentID == id);
/*Lots of other stuff unimportant to the question...*/
```

### Delete View

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Department

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<p class="text-danger">@ViewData["ConcurrencyErrorMessage"]</p>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Department</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Budget)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Budget)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Administrator)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Administrator.FullName)
        </dd>
    </dl>

    <form asp-action="Delete">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="DepartmentID" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="RowVersion" />
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

### Delete Post

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(Department department)
{ 
        try
        {
            if (await _context.Departments.AnyAsync(m => m.DepartmentID == department.DepartmentID))
            {
                _context.Departments.Remove(department);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException /* ex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Delete), new { concurrencyError = 
                true, id = department.DepartmentID });
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is passed in the body of the request.

Comment: The `blah blah blah` in the `Delete` method (`HTTP POST`)  is important because it shows you how it finds the "instance" based on `id` and deletes the db record, likely shows how it prevents overposting, and handles concurrency